# mongoldb update() wouldn't work

Tags: node.js, insert, mongoose

First I created the mongoose schema:

```
var cardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String,
  imageUrl: String
})
```

Then I defined model:

```
var Card = mongoose.model('Card', cardSchema)
```

Then I created a new card:

```
var newCard = new Card({
   userId: "bablaba"
});
```

Then the new card is saved correctly(I tested):

```
newCard.save(function(err,theCard){
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  console.log("saved");
  console.log(theCard);
  })
```

Now I need to update information in the card. I want to **add/insert** imageUrl into the saved new card.
Here's a few ways I tried:

1.

```
Card.where({ _id: _id }).update({
   $set: {imageUrl:"blablab"}
 });
```

2.

```
Card.update(_id,{$set:{imageUrl:"balbalab"}})
```

3.

```
Card.update({_id: updateInfo._id}, {note0:updateInfo.note0, note1: updateInfo.note1},{multi:true}, function(err, numberAffected){});
```

None of these three worked!!!
Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update),

> The operation is only executed when a callback is passed. To force
>   execution without a callback (which would be an unsafe write), we must
>   first call update() and then execute it by using the exec() method.

You are missing a callback function in the first case.

```
Card.where({ _id: "54a108be506225c82a56848b" }).update({
   $set: {imageUrl:"blablab"}
 },function(e,n){
    console.log(n);
});
```

or,

```
Card.update({_id: "54a108be506225c82a56848b"}, 
            {"imageUrl":"Hello"},
            {multi:true}, 
            function(err, numberAffected){});
```

Comment: um.. make sense, but it didn't work. It printed out the n, which was 0. but imageUrl is not inserted into the Card database

Comment: Yes, i didn't post without trying. Can you update your post with the document in question from your collection and the actual query you posted?

Comment: it worked. I have been testing out the code in a wrong schema. i have a little different schema defined in my internal codes.. sorry man, thank you so much for the help!! You are a great man !!

Comment: No problem. You're most welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it deemed helpful. Thanks !

Comment: you are the boss
can i find you on Facebook?

Comment: Am really sorry, but i am not on facebook. Feel free to start a chat whenever you have any doubts/questions. Will definitely do my best to help.

Comment: email? how can i find you then?
alright, fine, just wanted to make a friend. hahaha

Comment: I understand, please check my profile info. please feel free to contact me there.